# Is there a way to experimentally determine if a copolymer has a random monomer distribution or a blocky monomer distribution?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, polymers

I prepared a styrene-butadiene copolymer with a polar modifier. The expectation is that the copolymer is "random". Is there a way to confirm this using standard characterization techniques?

Comment: I've got this kind of confirmation but my polymer - a conjugated one -  was soluble and perhaps short enough to be characterised via HNMR. Otherwise NMR on polymers usually requires at least a specialist (of polymers, or NMR, or both).

Comment: Homework! What different properties will stat-PS-PB and block-PS-PB have?